# Remotely enable Windows 10 RDP without physical access

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, ssh, remote-desktop

Given that I have network access and valid login credentials to my Win 10 Pro machine which was upgraded overnight from Win 7, **how do I *remotely* enable Remote Desktop Protocol on my newly upgraded Win 10 machine** from a Linux server on the same network?

The Win 10 upgrade which ran overnight disabled RDP which I had previously enabled in Win 7. I can SSH in to a Linux machine on my home network and have network access to the Win 10 machine from there. I only have access to a Linux machine on the same network. I do not have physical access to the Win 10 machine right now.

Comment: Did you finish the initial setup's in windows 10?

Comment: If you enabled RDP in Windows 7 means after upgrade also the service will be enabled.

Comment: I initiated it last night and it ran overnight; I haven't had a chance to complete any prompts. It's probably sitting and waiting for input.

Comment: I think your machine is asking for some startup information like account name etc.